# HTTP Server Not Working (Python)

Tags: python, http, connection, wamp, server

This is my first time trying to get HTTP servers working on my computer, so I have run into a few technical difficulties.

I am using Python to develop the server, and I can access it on my localhost. But when I try to connect via the IP address, it does not work. I tried to connect on my phone as well, and that didn't work. From my understanding, I can connect to the server, but others cannot. I turned off Windows Firewall, and it still didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

handl = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
s = SocketServer.TCPServer(("localhost",2138),handl)
s.serve_forever()
```

If it makes any difference, I have had the same problem with WAMP Server. I turn off firewall and run it, and I cannot connect from other devices. Moreover, I tried it at a different house on a different router, and it still didn't work. However, I can connect to my own WAMP Server.

I really do not understand what is going wrong, and I would be grateful if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your router is blocking you. You need to open the router configuration page, normally 192.168.1.1 or something similar, check the router manual. Then you need to set it up to foward the port to your server PC. The step to accomplish this vary from router to router, try googling "port forwarding your_router_here" no quotes, replace your_router_here with the router you are using.

Comment: Is this the default setting on most routers? It appears to occur on every one I am using.

Comment: Routers never have port forwarding set up out of the box. There is no way for the manufacturer to know how you will need it set up. You might try looking for your router here --> http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm . You also need to read the answers from other people about binding it to the proper interface, changing the `localhost` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Change `"localhost"` to a public IP of your network adapter and try again.

First of all, you have to ping through it which makes sure data line is clear.
Then try to visit it.

Comment: I tried it, and it told me "error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context", which is weird because I put it in the following format: ex."127.0.0.1". Thank you, though! :)

Comment: `127.0.0.1:port#` works for me. However localhost and `0.0.0.0:port#` don't. What's the difference among the 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can change "localhost" to "0.0.0.0" to listen on all IP addresses you have. This is simplest way to open service to other hosts.

Answer (score 1):

adding public IP worked for me though , you can try adding "0.0.0.0" to bind it to all interfaces if there is any problem with the interface you are binding to.